# Is there any way to add a new location to the list of places where nltk looks for the wordnet corpus?

Tags: python

I can't use the nltk wordnet lemmatizer because I can't download the wordnet corpus on my university computer due to access rights issues.

I get the following error when I try to do so:

```
**********************************************************************   
Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader
to obtain the resource: >>> nltk.download() Searched in:
    - '/home/XX/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

When I had the same issue at home, I could resolve it by two ways:

1. Using `nltk.download()`, the standard way and
2. Creating a new folder at location `/home/XX/nltk_data`  and just pasting the corpus directory inside it.

Now at the university I only have access to `/home/XX/bin` and not `/home/XX` directly. So is there anyway I could paste the wordnet corpus into `/home/XX/bin` and then somehow make nltk look for the corpus in that folder?

Answer (score 6):

```
import nltk;
```

Now, `nltk.data.path` is a list of locations where to search for the modules. You can just do:

```
nltk.data.path.append("your location/directory");
```

Comment: Do we need to do this one time or everytime we run the script?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to set the environment variable "NLTK_DATA" to tell NLTK where to look. http://nltk.org/data.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems editing the pyinstaller nltk-hook. After much research, I decided to go it alone in the code structure. I solved my problem by commenting on the lines:

`datas=[]`

`'''for p in nltk.data.path:
datas.append((p, "nltk_data"))'''`

`hiddenimports = ["nltk.chunk.named_entity"]`

What's more, you need to rename the file: pyi_rth__nltk.cpython-36.pyc to pyi_rth_nltk.cpython-36.pyc . This file have 1 more underline. Warning with the python version.